# Android recording volume

Tags: android, audio-recording, volume

I need to record audio file in Android, but i have low volume problem. The output track is has so low volume.
How can i increase recording volume ?

Is it possible ?

I use MediaRecorder

**UPDATE**

I use this code:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
               audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
```

is there any error that decrease volume ?

Recorder code:

```
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); // CHANGE THIS ?
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(outputAudio);
 recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
 recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
 recorder.setMaxDuration(Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.max_mills)));**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand there is no way to do this while recording, it all depends on your mic. But while playing, you can use the setVolume(float, float) method on MediaPlayer to increase the volume.

Comment: I think it is ok. But like I said the audio quality of the output track will depends on your mic in my knowledge. I dont think you have something in there that decrease the volume. Can you post all the code relating to the recording?

Comment: Unfortunately Mediaplayer setVolume() can only help when playing not recording. Have you tried this the 3GP format? like this recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); And I would get rid of audioManager.setStreamVolume() line just for checking. If after all this there is no improvement try another device and see. Like I said it depends on the mic.